# Classification perceptron implementation

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

I have written Percentron example in Python from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntKn5TPHHAk).

Here is the complete code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rnd
import matplotlib.animation as animation

NUM_POINTS = 5
LEANING_RATE=0.1

fig = plt.figure()  # an empty figure with no axes
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.xlim(0, 120)
plt.ylim(0, 120)
points = []
weights = [rnd.uniform(-1,1),rnd.uniform(-1,1),rnd.uniform(-1,1)]
circles = []


plt.plot([x for x in range(100)], [x for x in range(100)])

for i in range(NUM_POINTS):
    x = rnd.uniform(1, 100)
    y = rnd.uniform(1, 100)
    circ = plt.Circle((x, y), radius=1, fill=False, color='g')
    ax1.add_patch(circ)
    points.append((x,y,1))
    circles.append(circ)

def activation(val):
    if val >= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1;

def guess(pt):
    vsum = 0
    #x and y and bias weights
    vsum = vsum + pt[0] * weights[0]
    vsum = vsum + pt[1] * weights[1]
    vsum = vsum + pt[2] * weights[2]

    gs = activation(vsum)
    return gs;


def animate(i):
    for i in range(NUM_POINTS):
        pt = points[i]
        if pt[0] > pt[1]:
            target = 1
        else:
            target = -1
        gs = guess(pt)
        error = target - gs
        if target == gs:
            circles[i].set_color('r')
        else:
            circles[i].set_color('b')
        #adjust weights
        weights[0] = weights[0] + (pt[0] * error * LEANING_RATE)
        weights[1] = weights[1] + (pt[1] * error * LEANING_RATE)
        weights[2] = weights[2] + (pt[2] * error * LEANING_RATE)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

I expect the points plotted on graph to classify themselves to red or blue depending on expected condition (x coordinate > y coordinate) i.e. above or below reference line (y=x)

This does not seem to work and all points go red after some iterations.

What am I doing wrong here. Same is working in youtube example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code and the video and I believe the way your code is written, the points start out as green, if their guess matches their target they turn red and if their guess doesn't match the target they turn blue.  This repeats with the remaining blue eventually turning red as their guess matches the target.  (The changing weights may turn a red to blue but eventually it will be corrected.)

Below is my rework of your code that slows down the process by: adding more points; only processing one point per frame instead of all of them:

```
import random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

NUM_POINTS = 100
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

X, Y = 0, 1

fig = plt.figure()  # an empty figure with no axes
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.xlim(0, 120)
plt.ylim(0, 120)

plt.plot([x for x in range(100)], [y for y in range(100)])

weights = [rnd.uniform(-1, 1), rnd.uniform(-1, 1)]
points = []
circles = []

for i in range(NUM_POINTS):
    x = rnd.uniform(1, 100)
    y = rnd.uniform(1, 100)
    points.append((x, y))

    circle = plt.Circle((x, y), radius=1, fill=False, color='g')
    circles.append(circle)
    ax1.add_patch(circle)

def activation(val):
    if val >= 0:
        return 1

    return -1

def guess(point):
    vsum = 0
    # x and y and bias weights
    vsum += point[X] * weights[X]
    vsum += point[Y] * weights[Y]

    return activation(vsum)

def train(point, error):
    # adjust weights
    weights[X] += point[X] * error * LEARNING_RATE
    weights[Y] += point[Y] * error * LEARNING_RATE

point_index = 0

def animate(frame):
    global point_index

    point = points[point_index]

    if point[X] > point[Y]:
        answer = 1  # group A (X > Y)
    else:
        answer = -1  # group B (Y > X)

    guessed = guess(point)

    if answer == guessed:
        circles[point_index].set_color('r')
    else:
        circles[point_index].set_color('b')

        train(point, answer - guessed)

    point_index = (point_index + 1) % NUM_POINTS

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

I tossed the special 0,0 input fix as it doesn't apply for this example.

The bottom line is that if everything is working, they ***should*** all turn red.  If you want the color to reflect classification, then you can change this clause:

```
    if answer == guessed:
        circles[point_index].set_color('r' if answer == 1 else 'b')
    else:
        circles[point_index].set_color('g')

        train(point, answer - guessed)
```

Comment: Thanks..That helped. I am still new to neural network. Can you please some example which will up my NN knowledge from where it is now?

Comment: Sorry, @RahulTitare, I just watched the video and enhanced the code -- I have no knowledge of neural networks.  I hope someone else on SO reading this exchange can give you a pointer to some examples.